# Swiper.js - Disable touch swiping but slide programmatically

Tags: cordova, swiper.js

On my cordova app, I want to slide programmatically with `slideNext()` and `slidePrevious()` method but when I use allowSwipeToPrev et allowSwipeToNext params, methods are disabled.

How can I slide programmatically when touch swiping is disabled ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the parameter onlyExternal to true when you initialize a Swiper instance to control the slider only programmatically

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
   onlyExternal:true
});
```

and then control the sliding with the methods `slideNext()`, `slidePrev()` or `slideTo()`

Answer (score 1):

For Swiper 7 the new option is the following:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
   allowTouchMove: false
});
```